Is inclusion of a prime ideal in a non-prime ideal possible?
Let $R$ be a ring which has $p$ as a prime ideal. Can there exist a non-prime proper ideal $m$ of $R$ such that $p$ ⊊ $m$?

Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693801/examples-of-prime-ideals-that-are-not-maximal answer your question?

$(2)$ is a prime ideal in ${\bf Z}[x]$, contained in the non-prime proper ideal $(2,x^2)$.

The zero ideal $(0)$ in the ring $\mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal. However, it is contained in any other ideal of $\mathbb Z$, including the non-prime ideal $(6)$.
